# Run MFC App in Docker windowsservercore container

Tags: windows, docker, mfc

Has anyone successfully gotten an MFC app running in a docker container? How would I install these libraries so I can run an MFC app that is now a windows service?

Here is my current docker file:

FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/A/6AA4EDFF-645B-48C5-81CC-ED5963AEAD48/vc_redist.x64.exe /vc_redist.x64.exe
RUN C:\vc_redist.x64.exe /quiet /install

Comment: At the very least you'll have to distribute the MFC libraries. See [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute) for additional details.

Comment: Agreed, I thought I was doing that above by including the redistributable package outlined here : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads. The error I am seeing when starting the EXE is that it can't find a dll that is in fact in the bin of the exe.

Comment: You are deploying the runtime libraries for Visual Studio. They implement the CRT as well as C++ support features. MFC is a separate product and it needs to be installed separately. Unless you want to link statically against MFC. Depending on your project topology, this may not be recommended.